# Why do some users have a "x% accept rate" displayed by their name when they ask a question and others don't?

Tags: support

I've noticed on pages like [this one](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/24378/is-it-save-to-delete-my-first-project-rcproject-file-in-the-imovie-projects-f) or [this one](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/24415/legality-of-itunes-sharing) that the person asking the question has a message stating "x% accept rate", but on other pages like [this one](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/24409/startup-items-no-longer-load-in-lion) or [this one](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/24376/preview-often-does-not-allow-import-from-ipad) there is no such message. What determines whether the accept rate is posted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The site wants to wait until enough of a sample is present.

[The official criteria of accept rate display](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/new-question-asker-features/) is a little involved, but basically you need a few quality questions (after some question types are filtered out) before it shows your rate.

Comment: So the Stack Overflow blog is a good place to search to see how features work? That's perhaps even more helpful information than the actual answer to this question.